# What is the difference between Qt OpenGL module and Qt/3D

Tags: qt, opengl, 3d

The 3D examples in the Qt Sdk(under opengl)already can demostrated,but without Qt/3D there.So,what is the difference between Qt OpenGL module and Qt/3D?

Comment: So can we ust Qt/3D only?And why?

Comment: You can use Qt3D alone but sometimes you might have to use it along with Qt OpenGL. Most of of Qt3D classes are dependent on Qt OpenGL. I'd recommend starting with looking at the examples provided in the source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Qt/3D Reference Documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt3d-snapshot/index.html):

> **Qt/3D is a set of extension classes for the Qt OpenGL module** to enhance the use of OpenGL in Qt 4.7 and higher.
>
> Porting between desktop OpenGL and embedded OpenGL/ES has traditionally been difficult. Desktop OpenGL, OpenGL/ES 1.1, and OpenGL/ES 2.0 use different function names, and shaders versus fixed function pipelines. Writing a single OpenGL application that runs on all platforms is quite difficult, even for simple objects.

So Qt/3D is an extension to the normal Qt OpenGL module. Browse the links in that page for more details and tutorials/samples.

Comment: So can we use Qt/3D only?And why?

Comment: "can we use Qt/3D?" I have no idea. "And why?" How could I know? (I'm not you, I can't guess whether or why you'd use it.) Use it if you need it. Don't use it if you don't.

Comment: What i mean is: can we just use Qt/3D module  to implement 3D ,without using QtOpenGL module?

Comment: "Qt/3D is a set of extension classes for the Qt OpenGL module". It **extends** the OpenGL module. It's not a standalone thing.